# is it possible to select a string in linq to entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to to Linq and Entity framework in general. Is it possible to select a string as part of the query using linq?
In sql a string can be selected like this

```
SELECT 'broken', Name, Type
FROM car
Where status = 3
```

Is it possible to do this in linq? something around

```
iqueriable<car> = brokenCars.select(cars => new {cars."broken",cars.name, cars.type})...
```

Thanks in advance
Also sorry if the question is a bit misleading I didn't know how else to word it.

Comment: if you are trying to query for broken cars from the LINQ statement, use Where, something like

var cars = brokenCars.Where(cars => cars.Status == 'broken');

your sql is not valid to write this example effectively, please add more to your question about the source query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var cars = brokenCars.Where(c => c.status == 3)
                     .Select(c => new { status = "broken", c.name, c.type });
```